# ms project 2010 - how to show resources on a calendar?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I am using MS project 2010, I have added the required tasks and have allocated the resources.
Just wondering how I can get a view of a monthly calendar view that shows the resources allocated on each day?
I assume this would be a straight forward request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer:**

You can use the Calendar View and customize it to show Resources:

- From the View tab, select More Views under the Other Views drop down.
- Select Calendar and click Apply.
- Right-click in the calendar area and select Bar Styles.
- Under Task type, select All.
- From the Field(s) drop-down list, select Resource Names and click OK.

**Additional Information:**

The Calendar View shows *tasks*--the bars displayed are the tasks, so you might see multiple bars showing the same resource.

**Show resources at summary level:**

One trick you can use to consolidate the resource information is to "roll up" the resource names to the summary level and only show summary tasks on the Calendar view. See this post: [MS Project 2013: display resources on summary tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889766/ms-project-2013-display-resources-on-summary-tasks/25901025#25901025) for how to show the names of resources used on subtasks.

Then format the Calendar View like this:

- From the Bar Styles box, select All and change the Bar type to None.
- Select Summary and change Bar type to Bar, select a Pattern and Color and select Text1 from the Field(s) list; click OK
- Right-click in the Calendar area and select Layout Now

The result will be a calendar view showing summary task bars displaying the names of resources assigned to the subtasks.

For this purpose, I suggest you modify the macro in the link above so that resource names are not rolled all the way up, but only show for the direct summary tasks (e.g. comment out the block that starts with "If child.Summary...").

Comment: Awesome, just one thing though, I have sub tasks which have resources assigned, and if the sub tasks are not expanded they don't show up on the calendar, is this typical behaviour? or is there a flag I need to set?

Comment: @user2206329 see my additional comments on how to "rollup" resource names to summary tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Resource Usage view? This is arranged with time along the X-Axis and Resources on the Y-Axis. If you choose to display in days you will see the amount of hours any resource spends on that day, either broken down by all their tasks or aggregated across all their task if you roll it up.

Not quite a calendar view, but commonly used to determine resource loading on a daily basis.